# Equivalent to "Zone répétée" in Windows Forms (.net)

Tags: winforms, windev

Do somebody know what is the equivalent in Windows Forms to the "Zone répétée" control of Windev ?

I hesitate between DataGridView and ListView.

A "Zone répétée" in Windev (or "Looper" as in Windev you can code in french or english) is a little bit like a repeater in ASP.NET I believe.

You can edit it visually and insert data into it by using "ZoneRepeteeAjouteLigne" "LooperAddLine")

The number of columns can be modified (in screenshot, there are 3).
[image]

Comment: I think I've found solutions here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2b60ed1c-ae44-42cd-a204-bf22d0f19920/aspnet-repeater-like-control-in-winforms?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Comment: @CodeCaster What is "niche" : Windev or the term I've used ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218984/discussion-between-coutier-eric-and-codecaster).

Comment: I see that someone deleted one of my comments (before the second from @CodeCaster which he refers to by the way). By what right and who does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataRepeater from Visual Basic Power Packs seems the easiest solution. It seems compatible with Visual Studio 2019.

Documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/cc488280(v=vs.120)

Download here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25169